# how to add android beacon library in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, altbeacon, android-ibeacon

I have followed the exact steps mentioned at https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference/tree/eclipse but 
still i am unable to use android beacon library.

When i try to add android beacon library in my project Library(Properties->Android)  it shows red symbol and due to this i get error in my code.

Comment: Will need a bit more information than that, what exactly is the issue?

Comment: It show red cross symbol when i tried to add android beacon library in my project.

Comment: The red x means the project has a broken link path.

Comment: @EdGeorge: Then how to use android beacon library in my project. As i have followed the same steps which is mentioned at https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-

Comment: Try this
Go to Project Properties->Java Build Path ->Click on tab "Libraries"
Click on "Add Jars" Tab. Select -"android beacon library" and go to its libs project - Select its jar file and click on ok.
After that Click or tab - "Order and Export" make tick sign on android beacon library. At last click on OK.
Your error get resolve.

Comment: @Shane :it removes the error but it failed to launch the application and it show other error in logcat -"the beacon service is not properly connected"

Comment: Yeah It worked i was initially copied the android beacon library at desktop but now i have copied it into eclipse workspace and now i can successfully add library with green symbol and application also working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The directions on this page [Configuring the Android Beacon Library](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/configure.html) state that you should download and extract the archive file and then import the folder into Eclipse.